# Bound on determinant of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, upper-lower-bounds

Given bounds on the value of the determinant of an infinite dimensional square matrix $A$, what are the bounds on the determinant of the matrix exponential of that matrix?

Comment: Obviously a singular matrix $A$ with determinant $0$ can have a matrix exponential $e^A$ with nonzero determinant.  Can you explain more what context you have, e.g. what properties of $A$ are known?

Comment: It's equal to the trace of $A$.

Comment: @hardmath Does it suffice to limit the discussion to a sequence of square matrices of dimension $n\times n$ and take the limit as $n$ goes to $\inf$?

Comment: If it helps, the basis of the representation should be ordered.

Comment: Yours is the Question to frame, and it would make sense to ask for bounds that depend on $n$ in a way that allows the limit to be taken.  However I suspect your Question is motivated by an application that would permit more to be said than in the generality currently posed.

Comment: @hardmath Your restriction is sufficient.

Comment: As stated it is impossible to give such a bound.  For $n\ge 2$ the determinant of $e^A$ can be arbitrarily large for matrices such that $\det A = 0$.  So it is impossible to give a function $\Phi(\det A)$ that bounds $\det(e^A)$, even when we restrict $n=2$, much less for $n$ tending to infinity.

Comment: @hardmath that seems like an answer, why don’t you expand it and post it as such? You could outline e.g. why the det can be arbitrarily large even for singular matrices.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are asked to provide a bound on the determinant of $e^A$ in terms of the determinant of square matrix $A$, possibly allowing for the size $n$ to be used in formulating the bound in a manner that allows us to take a limit as $n\to \infty$.

To show that no bound of the requested form is possible, it suffices to construct a family of matrices $A_n$ of respective sizes $n\times n$ for all $n\ge 2$ such that $\det A_n = 0$ but $\det e^{A_n}$ is arbitrarily large.

Let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose entries are all equal to $a$.  Then for $n\ge 2$ we have duplicate rows and $\det A_n = 0$.  However the determinant of the matrix exponential, as @BillCook explains, is the exponential of the trace of the matrix.  In this case:

$$ \det e^{A_n} = e^{\operatorname{tr} A_n} = e^{na} $$

The requested bound would entail a sequence of real functions $\Phi_n$ so that for all sufficiently large $n$:

$$ \det e^{A_n} \le \Phi_n(\det A_n) $$

But we cannot provide such a function for any $n\ge 2$, much less for all sufficiently large $n$, because with the specific matrices $A_n$ it would mean:

$$ e^{na} \le \Phi_n(0) $$

However large the value $\Phi_n(0)$ is, we can always choose $a$ in a way that causes such an inequality to fail.  For example, $a = |\Phi_n(0)|$ would cause such a failure.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathrm{det}(e^A) = e^{\mathrm{tr}(A)}$$

So the determinant is the exponential of the trace. So you probably won't find many "bounds" because the actual value is pretty easy to compute.

However, you could say things like: Let $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}$ be the eigenvalue of maximum modulus (i.e. absolute value when all are real). Then $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) and so $|\mathrm{tr}(A)| \leq n|\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}|$ when $A$ is $n \times n$. Thus $\mathrm{det}(A) \leq e^{n|\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}|}$.

Comment: This answers the question I posted, but I phrased it poorly. I will update the question.

Comment: For the new version of the question, what do you mean by an "infinite dimensional" matrix? (I imagine you mean a linear operator on an infinite dimensional vector space.) This leads to the question, what do you mean by determinant in such a case? In such a context, it isn't even clear that a determinant is defined or an exponential exists.

Comment: If you’re still interested, I’ve added comments to the question.